# What is max for PWA caching? I can cache everything?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I need to know what's max for service worker & PWA cache? I know we can cache some CSS & JS files, but What's the situation with images & updated data + I can cache everything till the user can browse in SPA application without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the space available in the Chrome Developer Tools -> Application Tab -> Clear Storage Option.
It shows the usage of the space available and used. You can get limit for that browser from there.
You can check out this link for more info.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria#Storage_limits

Comment: Can you also please upvote if you are satisfied with the answer.  :-)